# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). moz-extension:136:52

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I am making a react app for google login and this error is coming in the console :

```
Object { error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:3000 has not been registered for client ID undefined. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID." }
```

I have checked many times, the authorized javascript origins are correctly written as http://localhost:3000

Here is my google login code :

```
<GoogleLogin 
              clientId={`${process.env.SHARE_US_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN}`}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                  className='bg-mainColor flex justiy-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none'
                >
                  <FcGoogle className='mr-4' />SignIn with Google
                </button>
              )}
              onSuccess={responseGoogle}
              onFailure={responseGoogle}
              cookiePolicy='single_host_origin'
            />
```

I have checked many times, the authorized javascript origins are correctly written as http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `http://127.0.0.1:3000` address to Authorized JavaScript origins in your project setup in Google Developers Console.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me. Added both localhost and your suggested address also but it didn't work.